# How manual dial in vicidial is implemented with asterisk?

Tags: asterisk, sip, sip-server, agi

I logged in using agc (agent) panel in vicidial and just to test manual dial, I just executed following MySql query fron cmd.

```
UPDATE vicidial_live_agents set external_dial='12122351880!!YES!NO!YES!!1478530720!!!!!!' where user='1001';
```

After this , i got a a call on my softphone (already configured).

I am unable to understand one thing, How can an explicit entry to the vicidial_live_agents table of mysql, make a call ?

Comment: What exactly in vicidial doc is unclear to you?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be messing with the database for calls.

If you configured everything correctly, you should recieve a call as soon as you log-in which will send you to a conference, you should hear a voice confirming it (you are the only one in this conference), all future calls will be connected to that conference, you should keep that call at all times and not control anything in the softphone.

If you need to make a manual calls you can either set the "Manual Dial Override" option in the campaign to "ALLOW ALL", which will enable a link in the agent screen labeled "Manual Dial" or you can use the agent_api with the external_dial function.

Answer (score 1):

What you have found is the raw method that the Agent API uses to implement a manual dial call. For more information on how the Agent API works, and for all of the options you can use with the "external_dial" function, take a look at the Agent API documentation:
http://vicidial.org/docs/AGENT_API.txt